# WIndows Universal MediaPlayer From BackgroundActivated Task Single Processs Model Invoked from WNS

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am trying to play a sound from a BackgroundActivated Task (Single Process) that is activated as a result of Windows Notification Service WNS event.

If the Applications is launched in the Foreground and then minimized ... Things work fine.

If the Application is not currently launched ... This does not work.
My App's OnBacgroundActivated:

```
 protected override async void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args) {
  PersistLog.v(TAG, "OnBackgroundActivated");
  await VANotification.Process(args.TaskInstance);
  //base.OnBackgroundActivated(args);
  PersistLog.v(TAG, "OnBackgroundActivated:Completed");
}
```

The VANotification.Proces

```
public async Task Process(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance) {
  PersistLog.v(TAG, "Process");
  var Deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
  RawNotification notification = (RawNotification)taskInstance.TriggerDetails;
  var msg = notification.Content;
  PersistLog.i(TAG, "Msg:" + msg);
  var a = Record(msg);
  await TTSSandSound.Say(a);
  Deferral.Complete();
  PersistLog.v(TAG, "Process:Complete!");
}
```

The TTSAndSound.Say ...

```
public static async Task Say(String text) {
  PersistLog.v(TAG, "Say:" + text);
  sSynthesize.Voice = SpeechSynthesizer.DefaultVoice;
  var ss = sSynthesize.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);
  var t = new TaskCompletionSource<MediaSource>();
  ss.Completed = (stream, status) => {
    var sr = stream.GetResults();
    MediaSource ms = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(sr,sr.ContentType);
    t.TrySetResult(ms);
  };
  var _ms = await t.Task;
  var r = await WaitFor(_ms);
  PersistLog.v(TAG, "Say:Complete:" + r);
}

private static async Task<bool> WaitFor(MediaSource ms) {
  var mp = new MediaPlayer();
  mp.Source = ms;
  var t = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
  mp.MediaEnded += (p, o) => {
      t.TrySetResult(true);
  };
  mp.MediaFailed += (p, o) => {
    t.TrySetResult(true);
  };
  mp.Play();
  return await t.Task;
}
```

I am actually not sure if this is a MediaPlayer problem or the fact that the BackgroundActivated task does not seem to honer the deferal. I can see from the log that the MediaPlayer finishes properly. But I get an App Suspending event about the same time I try to do a MediaPlayer Play ... And then none of the async code after the call to:

```
 await TTSSandSound.Say(a);
```

Seems to run. I have followed:
[Background media playback sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/dev/Samples/BackgroundMediaPlayback)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE ... THis always works when the App is in activated in forground mode when the WNS arrives.

The problem appears to be related to the fact that often the Background Activated Task in the same process as the foreground is being suspended before the MediaPlayer is setup properly.

In a few test cases .. the MediaPlayer seems to get setup properly ... and in those cases the MedialPlayer works correctly. But the async tasks not associated with the MediaPlayer still throw exceptions: .

```
at Hap.App.<OnBackgroundActivated>d_27.MoveNext()
```

This seems to be related to the Timing of the app being suspended. It seems that a Local Background Activated Task that is triggered by a WNS is only allowed less than 1 second before being suspended.